# Rails: What's going wrong in this Ajax call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I receive from my server-side tracebacks: `No route matches [POST] "/tracks/genlist"`

I made an action the handle an Ajax call. This is how I implemented it:

1. Under `routes.rb`, I added the line `get 'tracks/genlist'`
2. In my home (index.html.erb) view, I have the following call:

   ```
   <%= button_to('Generate Playlist', :action => 'genlist',:controller=>'tracks', :method => :get, :remote => true) %>
   ```
3. I am supposed to be able to have an updated pluck call from the Track database:

   **tracks_controller.rb**

   ```
   def genlist
       @tracks = Track.all
       @playlist = Track.pluck(:video_id)
   end
   ```
4. And finally, the Javascript that has to be fired off when the button_to form is submitted:

   **genlist.js.erb**

   ```
   alert(<%= raw (@playlist).to_json %>);
   ```

What am I doing wrong here? I've been stuck on this for quite a bit, if anyone wants any more information about the errors or more details, do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` is because the `action` `genlist` does not exist in the current controller but exists in `TracksController`.  You can specify the controller in your `button_to` link which should fix this issue:

```
<%= button_to('Generate Playlist', :action => 'genlist', :controller => 'tracks' , :method => :get, :remote => true) %>
```

And in your `config/routes.rb` ensure you have the following:

```
resources :tracks do 
    collection do 
        get 'genlist'
    end
end
```

**Update:**

`button_to` helper does not support any `method` parameter as one expects to use it.  The `method` parameter is appended to the generated URI query string e.g. '/tracks/genlist?method=post' and used in the `action` of the `form` that the `button_to` helper generates.

Here is the use of `button_to` helper and what it generates (removed authenticity_token hidden field from the output):

```
<%= button_to('Generate Playlist', :action => 'genlist', :controller => 'tracks' , :method => :get, :remote => true) %>
# <form method="post" class="button_to" action="/tracks/genlist?method=get&remote=true">
#     <div>
#         <input type="submit" value="Generate Playlist">
#     </div>
# </form>
```

Although the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to states that `:post, :get, :delete, :patch, and :put` methods are supported but does not clearly state what happens to these methods.

So instead of using `button_to` helper for a `get` request in this case, use `link_to` helper as following:

```
<%= link_to('Generate Playlist', :action => 'genlist', :controller => 'tracks' , :method => :get, :remote => true) %>
```

which will generate:

```
<a data-remote="true" href="/tracks/genlist?method=get">Generate Playlist</a>
```

Comment: Now I am linked to this error message: `No route matches [POST] "/tracks/genlist"`

Comment: @Louis93 And it's true; that's a GET route, not a POST. When there's a routing problem, not including the relevant section of `routes.rb` makes it difficult to help.

Comment: I did mention it in the original question as 1.), let me add it to a pastie.

Comment: Please update your routes.rb with 
`resources :tracks do 
    get 'genlist'
end
`, at the top where you have `resources :tracks` and remove your `get 'tracks/genlist'` from the bottom.

Comment: @vinodadhikary changed, I now get: `No route matches {:action=>"genlist", :controller=>"tracks", :method=>:get, :remote=>true}`

Comment: Please post your rake routes output.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  My bad, you didn't want `genlist` for a particular `track_id`.  I've updated my answer for the `resource` declaration.  Please try that and report back.

Comment: Please stop posting images and links: put the information required to answer the question *into the question*.

Comment: @vinodadhikary, back to `No route matches [POST] "/tracks/genlist"` :(

Comment: Just to confirm, you see this message in your logs when you click the "Generate Playlist" button correct?  Also please check to make sure that navigating to that URI directly on your browser produces expected result.

Comment: @vinodadhikary This is correct. Here's the URI that I navigate to: `http://localhost:3000/tracks/genlist?method=get&remote=true`

Comment: Okay figured out the problem, tried it out :).  You cannot use `button_to` helper for `get` method, use `link_to` instead and apply some `css` to make the link appear like a button.  I am going to update my answer with this information.